# Android get value of any column from any cursor giving the corresponding id

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have created `Cursor` from any database table. It consists value of _id and corresponding name. For further operation, I need the value of "name" for any specific "_id". How it is possible using the Cursor.

Comment: Why is this more complex than just using a SELECT WHERE with the _id you need?

Comment: I am using cursor to show a list of id. Depending upon the user selection, I want to show the name depending on the selected id. Then I do not want to access the database again, because I have the cursor. Any way to retrieve the name from id?

Answer (score 3):

```
String selecttSqlStr2 = "SELECT * FROM Tablename  WHERE TRIM(QST_Id) = '" + _id;

Cursor c = datasource.execSelectSQL(selecttSqlStr);//datasource is object for opening database
c.moveToFirst();
String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
```

Comment: I do not want that. I am using cursor to show a list of id. Depending upon the user selection, I want to show the name depending on the selected id. Then I do not want to access the database again, because I have the cursor. Any way to retrieve the name from id?

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate searching code that is already implemented inside SQLite? Please note that the data stored in the `Cursor` does not have indexes, so the separate query is likely to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple you can get it by either of following way

String id = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("id") ); // id is column name in db

or

String id = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(0)); // id is first column in db